# Call library function with unknown number of args

Tags: c

I have to load function (taking constant number of arguments like `pow` or `sin`) from `so` library and execute it with arguments given in command line. Name of the library and function are also given in command line arguments. Moreover I have a string encoding number of parameters and their type, e.g. "ii" means two integers. So I can load this library using `dlopen()` and load function using `dlsym` but I can't imagine how to pass all arguments to this function while their number is unknown before the execution.

Comment: You can't really. You have to think up some other design (using e.g. arrays instead).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude may be use inline assembly and put all parameters on stack before pushing call of function?

Comment: But then you're not programming in C anymore. And it will definitely not be portable. Or something I recommend in general.

Comment: You can have a very large switch statement with all possible calls.

Comment: @stark and it will cover just first set of cases. Yes, it is nice idea, i'll try it. I think to overdose five cases is enough.

Comment: There is no universal solution in C. Perhaps in some future version there will be macros like `va_create` and `va_add_arg`

Comment: @stark write your comment in answer

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond can I `mmap` all arguments in memory and make function understand that it should read there?

Comment: `mmap` has nothing to do with it. An `intptr_t` array  could be converted into `va_list` -- on some platforms. Others (amd64 for example) pass arguments in registers, so this won't work. I'd like to repeat: There is no universal solution in C.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Ok portability is problem. And if I use only Linux-i386 for instance?

Comment: Then your idea using Assembly might work.

Comment: Calling a `foo(xxx, ...)` function with too many arguments is OK.  Is the maximum numbers of arguments the function may receive known?

Comment: @chux my functions are NOT variable arguments. They like `cos`, `pow` and similar.

Comment: Are the function arguments types all `double`?

Comment: @chux no. It can be `int`, `char *` or sth else

Comment: @chux I am implementing now realization using inline assembly and I think that I can mark question as answered, though this solution was not explained in details here.

Comment: Note: You can post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @chux After finishing I will share the explanation of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch statement on the possible set of input parameters would allow you to call the library.  Something like:

```
switch(param) {
   PARAM_II: rc = (*func)(int1, int2);
   break;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C supports vararg calls, where the variable part is represented by an ellipse in the function declaration. It is defined in 7.15 Variable arguments  of the standard. That's is a rather obscure part of C, but heavily used in standard library for the `*printf` and `*scanf` functions family, as well as the `execl` one.

It is obscure IMHO, because you need some magic to guess what arguments were actually passed. For `*printf` and `*scanf`, you rely on the format string to declare that, for `execl`, you assume that it is a list of C strings (null terminated char arrays), terminated with a NULL pointer.

This kind of call is good for use cases where the caller knows the number of arguments (again think about `*printf`). If the number of arguments can vary at run-time, for example the command line arguments, an array is more appropriate. Not surprisingly, the `main` function receives its argument list as a array + array length. If you want to be able to pass the command line arguments to another function (be it in a dll or not) just mimic it and pass an array either with its length as another parameter, or with the convention that it shall be terminated with a NULL pointer.

Comment: that is the main problem for me! For example I received `pow` and two arguments. I don't know how to pass array to `pow`.

Comment: @Tehada: I just missed the point. I was speaking of the callee part, while your problem is the caller part. I cannot imagine a general solution without pushing arguments to the stack and calling the function in assembly language. Anyway this clearly does not answer your question and will be delete in a while...

Comment: Please don't delete your answer -- it helped me understand the appropriate solution. As I don't care about portability in this case I can use `mmap` to place all in virtual memory. So now I have pointer to function and arguments. May be send it all to `PIPE` and then `mmap` it?